# Does Meteor have a mongo injection issue with the ACL?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Meteor docs http://docs.meteor.com/#dataandsecurity under "Input validation" say:

> Meteor allows your methods and publish functions to take arguments of
>   any JSON type. (In fact, Meteor's wire protocol supports EJSON, an
>   extension of JSON which also supports other common types like dates
>   and binary buffers.) JavaScript's dynamic typing means you don't need
>   to declare precise types of every variable in your app, but it's
>   usually helpful to ensure that the arguments that clients are passing
>   to your methods and publish functions are of the type that you expect.
>
> Meteor provides a lightweight library for checking that arguments and
>   other values are the type you expect them to be. Simply start your
>   functions with statements like check(username, String) or
>   check(office, {building: String, room: Number}). The check call will
>   throw an error if its argument is of an unexpected type.
>
> Meteor also provides an easy way to make sure that all of your methods
>   and publish functions validate all of their arguments. Just run meteor
>   add audit-argument-checks and any method or publish function which
>   skips checking any of its arguments will fail with an exception.

The mongo injection problem is explained in more details in the security talk: https://www.meteor.com/blog/2013/08/02/meteor-devshop-6-devshop-live-security-meteor-ui

So my questions are:

1. one has to do `check` before calls to Mongo or risk sending untrusted JS objects into the db thus possibly opening up to a Mongo injection vulnerability? **- YES, one should add `audit-argument-checks` in his app to protect against this**
2. this has to be done on all mongo actions and not just on `find`? **- not sure**
3. if 1) or 2) are true, then how does this translate to the use of ACL-style database access rules (`collection.allow`/`collection.deny`) where calls to mongo api aren't filtered by manual `check` calls but rather left to the client? **- you can add `check` to the allow/deny functions, but it depends on 2) if and when this is necessary**

Answer (score 5):

1. Yes. All kinds of bad things can happen if you blindly trust the values passed by the client to a method call.
2. This gets into theory which probably very few people can give you a straight answer on, so why take the risk? I strongly recommend adding [audit-argument-checks](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/auditargumentchecks) to all of your projects just to be safe.
3. With respect to `allow` and `deny`, `find` calls are not at risk here because the data is already on the client (presumably your publish function should have already published the correct documents). I think the risk in this case has more to do with bad data than it does with security. It's easy enough to just add `check` calls inside the rules. For example:

---

```
Posts.allow({
  insert: function(userId, doc) {
    check(doc, {
      _id: String,
      message: String,
      createdAt: Date
    });
    return true;
  }
});
```

This will fail to insert a new post from the client if the document does not conform to the schema.

Comment: Very good answers! So basically, to make meteor secure one should pretty much routinely add `audit-argument-checks` too, not just remove `insecure` and `autopublish`? However, as far as I can tell from package description, it doesn't cover `check` in allow/deny, but I guess that boils down to the correct answer for 2) :)

Comment: You got it - remove those 2 and add that 1 for a solid start on security. Yes, audit-argument-checks does not enforce that you use `check` in allow/deny rules.

Answer (score 0):

The `allow` and `deny` rules are checked on the server before it lets client queries run. You can absolutely use `check` inside your allow/deny functions, on both the client and the server. You don't write an allow rule for reads on the client, instead use `check` in your publish function.

Comment: Thank you :) Question, when you say "you can absolutely use" do you mean "you should/must absolutely use" or "you should do that but why bother in cases of x,y,z", none of the examples from meteor.com or various online tutorials do the `check` spam so I'm wondering whats the guideline for doing this?

Comment: You can use check if you want, and I recommend it because it's a very easy way to check a value's type. However, you will probably also want to do other validation that check cannot do alone - field length, user id, uniqueness, etc. What's important is that your allow/deny rules are strong enough that you can narrow queries down to only trusted ones, according to your business rules. Whether you use check or not to accomplish this is up to you - after all check is written in JavaScript and there is nothing it can do that you can't without it.

Comment: Thats useful, why does one need to check for field length? Ddos prevention or just for basic data validation?

Comment: Just basic data validation, depending on your business rules. For example, StackOverflow restricts comments to 600 characters. GitHub only lets you create as many private repositories as you are paying for. A game would only allow your weapon to carry a certain amount of ammo. It may be that you don't want to check for field lengths - but that all depends on your specific needs.

Comment: Ok, yes, that goes without saying I hope :) I'm wondering is there a security undertone to that validation, can one insert an arbitrarily large dataset through a collection.insert and jeopardize database stability? (if this is so, then this kind of validation is something you *must* do rather then something that you *should* do)

Comment: I'm not sure what would happen in that case, but yes it seems useful to check for things like this no matter what. There's almost always some theoretical limit where a string or array should be cut off, for display purposes if nothing else. Note that you can also modify the document (for inserts) or modifier (for updates) from within your allow and deny rules. This basically allows you to sanitize invalid data without raising a validation error.